# How to pass requested url to specific place when type in Browser

Tags: networking, browser, port-forwarding, web-hosting

I am developing an application and for testing purpose I want it to put on www.

So I have followed some methods.
I have Spring MVC Java Web Application and I am hosting it on IIS Server, So I have to Route/Forward request from IIS to Tomcat.

I have followed Following Step :

1. Create Web Farm (In Application Request Routing) :

[image]

2. Setup Server Details :

[image]

3. Now click ok and save the Farm and then I have make URL rewrite rule :

[image]

4. When I run in browser `http://localhost/` then it passes to my port 8080, otherwise before I ll have to give 8080 port explicitly. Here `192.168.1.16` is my PC `IP`.
   On browser run :[image]

Now My Question :

my office have already domain `office.orgname.info`, this is not real name.Now I want to open my web application on `spring.office.orgname.info`, and how to do so I don't know.
my domain `IP` is `115.16.221.34` (Not Real, for Example).

So Any Great Help for it..

Answer (score 0):

You should get your Domain administrator to create an A-type DNS record for you. Ask them for the following record:

```
sprint.office.orgname.info IN A 115.16.221.34
```

On Windows 2008 this can be done on the domain controller by going to Administrative Tools->DNS and then in the Forward Lookup Zone for office.orgname.info right-click and select 'New Host (A or AAAA).

Comment: Sir I have `Win Server 2012 R2`, it doesn't show `DNS` option in Admin Tools and We have already one application so How to bind other application on same `IP`.

Comment: You should use IIS bindings. This will allow you to 'route' an incoming request based on the hostname used in the request. Here is a [Technet example](http://technet.microsoft.com/nl-nl/library/cc731692%28v=ws.10%29.aspx). Google should be able to tell you how to create an A record on Windows 2012.